# Есть класс с библиотекой android.app.Fragment, надо перейти на android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Фрагменты используют библиотеку android.support.v4.app.Fragment мне нужно чтобы и меню использовало ту же библиотеку. Подскажите как это сделать

```
package com.example.admin.testattachment;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.example.admin.testattachment.FragmentMenu.FragmentCatalogProgram;
import com.example.admin.testattachment.FragmentMenu.FragmentDirectory;
import com.example.admin.testattachment.FragmentMenu.FragmentHome;
import com.example.admin.testattachment.FragmentMenu.FragmentMeasurements;
import com.example.admin.testattachment.FragmentMenu.FragmentMyProg;
import com.example.admin.testattachment.FragmentMenu.FragmentNotebook;
import com.example.admin.testattachment.FragmentMenu.FragmentStats;
import 
com.example.admin.testattachment.FragmentMenu.FragmentTrainingProcess;    


public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();


    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = FragmentHome.class;

    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the FragmentHome/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.itemHome) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;

    fragmentClass = FragmentHome.class;
    if (id == R.id.itemHome) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentHome.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.trnProcess) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentTrainingProcess.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.measurements) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentMeasurements.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.stats) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentStats.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.directory) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentDirectory.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.myProgram) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentMyProg.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.catalogProgram) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentCatalogProgram.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.notebook) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentNotebook.class;
    }

    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    item.setChecked(true);
    setTitle(item.getTitle());

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Удалите все что связано с импортом фрагментов и импортируйте  их заново.

Comment: FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
Ошибка:

Required:
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
Found:
android.app.FragmentManager

Comment: Нашол такой ответ:Используйте getSupportFragmentManager(), или измените FragmentManager с (android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager) на android.app.FragmentManager